# Difference between bpy.context and context in an Operator or Panel

Tags: python

To write a custom operator, an `execute(self, context)` method must be defined for it. Similarly, a panel needs a `draw(self, context)` method.

What is the difference between accessing `bpy.context` directly and accessing the `context` passed into these methods? In all my testing, they appear to produce exactly the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Just found this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221613/is-it-ever-ok-to-use-bpy-context-instead-of-operator-context?rq=1

Seems related

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.context` can differ from `context` depending on how the operator or panel is invoked.  `bpy.context` will not be changed by an operator override but `context` will, for example.  Always use `context` rather than `bpy.context` in a situation where `context` is passed as an argument.

Comment: I figured that's a good general rule, but what's a situation where it would make a difference?

Comment: As I said, when you want to use a context override so you can, for example, do things in the 3d viewport from code running in the Python console, or from a script that's run from the text editor, rather than as an operator.

Comment: @MartyFouts maybe he is asking for a specific example where the result is different so he can test and see it.

Comment: @AnsonSavage said differently: using `bpy.context` is like "synthesizing" your own context for use in a quick script you might be writing, where as the `(self, context)` in an operator class is basically a placeholder for the future context you will pass to your operator when you run it. Whenever you do anything in blender there is a context object that is always being updated with new data and every operator takes this context as it's first argument.

Comment: So basically when you're just writing out a quick routine to rename some objects or whatever you'll probably have something like `import bpy; for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: # do a thing;`. There you use `bpy.context`. On the other hand, writing an operator class you do something like `def execute(self, context): self.obj = context.edit_object; # do a thing`. Using the implicit context from invoking the operator. That's the difference.

Comment: Fundamentally they are the same thing at the end of the day, but you might run into weirdness where the bpy.context is not exactly referencing the most up to date data as you want, whereas the context that is passed to the operator is guaranteed to be the bleeding edge, so you want to try to use that in relevant situations.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Interesting, okay, that makes sense! Yeah, that's the main reason I've been wondering, because in all my addon-writing, I haven't noticed a difference. Thanks!!

Comment: @Jakemoyo They are not fundamentally the same thing at the end of the day.  There are many `context` objects in a running blender instance.  `bpy.context` refers to a specific one of those many contexts.  `context` passed as an argument may point to that one, but often does not.  You need to understand it this way in order to understand how overrides work

Comment: Okay, that still doesn't really change my explanation.